# Visualize big git graph

Tags: git

I would like to analyse to git project with a common history but forked since a long time.

Is there a way to display git history with a long commit history? Each git client I know don't allow to zoom out the git graph.

Comment: Visualizing large graphs is a generally-hard problem. One specific thing that helps a lot in Git graphs is to use `git log`'s `--simplify-by-decoration` to discard most nodes, retaining only those required for the graph structure (branch-and-merge nodes) and any "labeled" node (one with a branch or tag name, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`tig`](https://jonas.github.io/tig/) and zoom out your console to visualise the branches.